# как мне посчитать MAPE для прогноза Prophet на Python?

Tags: python

По какой формуле можно посчитать MAPE(средняя абсолютная ошибка в процентах) для прогноза Prophet на Python

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mape+formula&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr

Comment: https://vedexcel.com/how-to-calculate-mape-in-python/